# Is it possible that Deflater.deflate will increase the size of the data?

Tags: java, security, compression

In Java there's a method `java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(byte[])` and I was wondering is it possible for someone to create some data that would increase the size of input data rather than shrinking.

Assuming that scenario is possible, what would the result be?  Data Loss? Buffer overflow? Perhaps do something more malicious and overwrite other parts of the VM and inject code?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering is it possible for someone to create some data that would increase the size of input data rather than shrinking.

Yes,random data cannot be compressed. Data which has already been compressed is hard to compress.

> what would the result be?

More data than you started with.

> Data Loss?

No.

> Buffer overflow?

If you have a bug in your program, possibly. but not normally.

It doesn't have to be malicious, it just has to be pretty random e.g already compressed.